# How to get the react navigator state outside the root react navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

This is the thing:
I have a react-native application on mobile, and I'm trying to do some authority check action when the user has left my app and get back. I want to avoid doing an authority check on the login screen and considering the existing application component tree, I want to get the current route for me to use. Now, I'm using **5.x** version react-navigation.

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAppStateChange = (): void => {
      // Authority check action
    };
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <RootNavigator />
          <OverlayActivityIndicator />
          <ActionSheet />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Now I meet the problem:
**I don't know how to do to get the current route outside the root navigator.**

My last choice is integrating the current route into the redux store, and that will be making my application more complex.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can refer this for getting navigation outside components](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop)

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}


//whereas 
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```